# Pivot table Values are now screwy

Tags: excel, excel-2003, pivot, pivot-table, vba

In Excel 2003, I have a macro that accidentally tried selecting a page field item (New York) that didn't exist. This renamed the currently selected page field (Alabama) to the value I tried to select (New York).

I now have 3 or 4 values that are now wrong. Is there a way to refresh these pivot table values to the correct values **without recreating the pivot table from scratch**?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code -

```
Sub Clean_AllPivotsOnSheet()
Dim pt As PivotTable
For Each pt In ActiveSheet.PivotTables
pt.PivotCache.MissingItemsLimit = xlMissingItemsNone
Next pt
End Sub
```

Then refresh the Pivot Table.